# SVG animate (rotate) all graphics around a center point

Tags: css, animation, svg, rotation

I have a simple graphic SVG

[image]

I would like it to rotate around the center point. It doesn't have to be smooth, just a rotation 90 and back every second.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 27 27" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27 27;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<rect x="0" width="27" height="27"/>
<rect x="8" y="11" class="st0" width="1" height="5"/>
<rect x="9" y="10" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="10" y="9" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="11" y="8" class="st0" width="5" height="1"/>
<rect x="13" y="6" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="14" y="7" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="14" y="9" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="13" y="10" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="18" y="11" class="st0" width="1" height="5"/>
<rect x="17" y="16" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="16" y="17" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="11" y="18" class="st0" width="5" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="17" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="13" y="16" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="12" y="19" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<rect x="13" y="20" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Is there an animation where I can rotate these SVG graphics around the center point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`animateTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform):

```css
.st0 {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      values="0 14 14; 90 14 14; 0 14 14"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <rect x="0" width="27" height="27"/>
    <rect x="8" y="11" class="st0" width="1" height="5"/>
    <rect x="9" y="10" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="10" y="9" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="11" y="8" class="st0" width="5" height="1"/>
    <rect x="13" y="6" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="14" y="7" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="14" y="9" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="13" y="10" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="18" y="11" class="st0" width="1" height="5"/>
    <rect x="17" y="16" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="16" y="17" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="11" y="18" class="st0" width="5" height="1"/>
    <rect x="12" y="17" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="13" y="16" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="12" y="19" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
    <rect x="13" y="20" class="st0" width="1" height="1"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a 90 rotation without the smooth movement? So 0 to 90 and back in 1s?

Comment: Updated to fit your specs.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. I meant to remove the spin effect. To make it static transition from one point to the next without the transition. Like a mechanical movement without the 'in between' sweep.